# Методика реализации слайдера изображений в приложении iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa, uikit

Буду признателен, если кто подкинет идею, как реализовать в приложении (*iOS, Swift*) слайдер изображений, многим известным как "карусель" (*Carousel*).
Идея такова, что при переходе из списка объектов к подробному описанию, на странице объекта половину экрана занимает изображение, нижняя часть экрана под описание. Необходимо в части изображения иметь возможность скроллом проматывать несколько фотографий.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю тебе стоит взглянуть вот сюда: [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)